# How to get rid of integer overflow warning?

Tags: c++, int, overflow, unsigned-integer

In my C++ code I have an expression where I multiply unsigned long integer to an int to assign the result to unsigned long int. I am getting a warning as 'overflowed returned value'. I tried to cast the int to unsigned long but it did not help. Any suggestions...

The expression is something like this-

```
uint64_t size = 0;
uint64_t value = getvalue();
int pageSize= getPageSize();
size = value*(uint64_t)pageSize;
```

Comment: Can you paste your code here?

Comment: If overflow is intended and you just want to suppress the warning, try to use `unsigned int` instead of plain `int`.

Comment: overflow is not intended and the function which return plain int can not be changed to return unsigned long neither the return value 'size'.

Comment: Which compiler and version are we talking about here?  This doesn't repro with gcc/g++ 4.5.2. And I tried with -Wall, -Wextra, and -pedantic and variations of -Wstrict-overflow=N

Comment: This appears in a static code checker tool..

Comment: And the name of that tool is???? (Hint - full disclosure earlier means we don't have to guess)

Comment: @polapts Just because `getPageSize()`(funny, should return a `size_t` probably) doesn't return an unsigned value doesn't mean it can't be stored as one. I think your code checker is paranoid, but it's right: nothing you've shown guarantees that the multiplication won't overflow a `uint64`.  It would probably be happier if value was a plain `int`.  What is `sizeof(int)` on your machine?

Comment: @selbie The tool is Coverity. Also, getPageSize() returns an 'int' and not size_t (declared in unistd.h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
size = value*(uint64_t)(unsigned int)pageSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tool probably has a way to set an exception for this line of code.

If the tool is truly clever, this is the only way, for there *really* is a risk of overflow here (as an `int` may not accomodate `2^64-1`).